# With new v2 flight-offers endpoint includedAirlineCodes & exlcludedAirlineCodes cannot be used together?

Tags: amadeus

In the previous version, V1, Low-fare search, these two parameters could both be used. Is that no longer possible? These parameters:

`{'adults': 1, 'children': 0, 'currencyCode': 'USD', 'departureDate': '2020-09-30', 'destinationLocationCode': 'FLL', 'excludedAirlineCodes': 'NK,B6', 'includedAirlineCodes': 'DL', 'infants': 0, 'nonStop': 'false', 'originLocationCode': 'MSP', 'returnDate': '2020-10-07', 'travelClass': 'ECONOMY'}`

Generate this error:

`{'errors': [{'status': 400, 'code': 2668, 'title': 'PARAMETER COMBINATION INVALID/RESTRICTED', 'detail': 'excludedAirlineCodes and includedAirlineCodes are not compatible'}]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Flight Offers Search API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference) (v2) we fixed something that was confusing for users: if you use `includedAirlineCodes` you only get the flights of the airline(s) specified (so it excludes all other airlines). Using `includedAirlineCodes` and `excludedAirlineCodes` at the same time is not possible.

Comment: In the [Low-Fare Search documantation](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-low-fare-search/api-reference) `includeAirlines` is defined: "if specified, the flight offer will include at least one segment per bound marketed by one of these airlines." Perhaps I did not understand what "bound" means, but I assumed results would include "at least one" itinerary from that/those carrier(s) **plus** other results, not limited to **only** those carriers.